# Edit interaction within all the visualisation in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have data and I want to calculate the average training hrs per employee and wanted to show it in card visualisation. But the problem is when I click on any graph suppose a donut chart showing male and female, when u click on male then all the graphs will change instantly and show data according to male. But that card where I have taken training hrs/empl in values which shows 19.2 (for eg) that card doesn't change accordingly which is supposed to change.

**What I have tried** -

Created a new column

```
TR_HRS_PR_EMP =
CALCULATE (
    DIVIDE (
        SUM ( 'TRAINING_DATA'[Training Hours] ),
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'TRAINING_DATA'[Employee Code] )
    ),
    FILTER (
        'TRAINING_DATA',
        'TRAINING_DATA'[Source] = "2020-21"
            || 'TRAINING_DATA'[Source] = "2019-20"
            || 'TRAINING_DATA'[Source] = "2018-19"
    )
)
```

**My data-**

| Employee Code | Training Hours | Source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 012 | 5 | 2019-20 |
| 665 | 2 | 2018-19 |
| 8875 | 2 | 2018-19 |
| 980 | 2 | 2018-19 |
| 1132 | 7 | 2020-21 |
| 6221 | 2 | 2018-19 |

This is a small portion of my data, I hope I have made clear what my problem is. I don't have deep knowledge in Power BI just need some suggestions from power bi experts to solve my problems. Please let me know whether my question depicts the exact problem.

Comment: Can you confirm that the other visuals are set up to [cross-filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-reports-visual-interactions) the card?

Comment: @Alexis Olsen no, actually I have set edit interaction for each and every graph(graphs and charts only) in format option not whith cards. Is that I have to do only?. Set Edit interaction within all charts and cards?

Comment: That's the first thing I'd try. If cross-filtering is disabled, then it clearly won't cross-filter.

Comment: Ok I'll try that but other cards which are present that changes with every click and I also I didn't change the interaction only that card which I have made with TR_HRS_PR_EMP column dosnt change

Comment: I checked, my interactions within all the graphs charts cards and slicers are active, still only that particular card dosnt changes upon clicking. Please help me solve this.

Comment: Do training hours and gender information coming from same table? If different table, are the connected to each other?

Comment: @mkRabbani sir same table